# Dynamics CRM: Is there a way to impersonate OrganizationData service?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm

I have some legacy code which for now I want to reuse in rewritten application. This code was used in silverlight, where user credential where available, but now it is supposed to run on server, so I need to impersonate it. Unfortunately, the code uses CRM OrganizationData service (https://crm/OnBoarding/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/) and I cannot find any way to turn impersonation on.

Is there a way to do it? I would like to avoid using NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting the CrmServiceClient with System Administrator credentials you are able to set the CallerId property to impersonate the user.

CallerId would be the SystemUserId on SystemUser.

Comment: CrmServiceClient connects to the OrganizationService.svc, not to the OrganizationData.svc. Those are completely different services.